To what extent are Langlands conjectural global L-functions unique?
Question
To what extent do the properties that are conjectured of L-functions determine them?
Explanation
Following Shahidi: So Langlands defines local L functions associated to unramified representations of a group $G(k_\nu)$, $\tau$, and its dual group ${}^LG$, $\sigma$. These look something like this
$$L_\nu(s, \tau, \sigma) = det(I - \tau(\sigma) q^{-s})^{-1} $$
Then conjectures that there should be a global analogue such that
$$L(s, \tau, \sigma) = \prod_\nu L_\nu(s, \tau_\nu, \sigma_\nu)$$
at least at the unramified places. The point is then to find the local factors for the ramified places. He also conjectures that these should have some properties.
The exact nature and extent of these properties is hard to track down, Borels article "Automorphic L-Functions" (14.2) specifies that they should at least be meromorphic, have a functional equation and maybe agree with certain other L-functions that appear in number theory.
So my specific questions are: Is there an "up to date" list of properties that these L-functions are expected to have, and to what extent do these properties define them uniquely?
Context
In Shahidi's "A Proof of Langlands' Conjecture on Plancherel Measures" he shows that certain related normalising factors are unique, moreover he defines some global L-functions. Other cases of global L-functions have been constructed in the literature and shown to satisfy the required properties above (not more) and I wonder to what extent I should think of these as being "done" or fixed, might they change as a more uniform treatment becomes possible?
Thanks a lot.
Related question1, although Kevin is not asking about the L-functions in particular.

Here is one possible answer: One property automorphic $L$-functions should have is that they should all arise from the standard $L$-function of automorphic representations of $GL_n$. The local factors of the automorphic representation of $GL_n$ at unramified places are then determined by the local factor of the $L$-function, and the automorphic representation is uniquely determined by multiplicity $1$, so this condition suffices to determine the whole $L$-function.

However, proving this condition is satisfied requires cases of functoriality which are usually harder than simply constructing the corresponding $L$-function.

@WillSawin my understanding (limited) is that even the global L-functions for $GL_n$ are not really determined by anything structural? There is some candidates that "work" for some narrow conditions, but they are not really unique in any mathematical sense (perhaps sociologically they are the only candidates though)?

@WillSawin I was also under the impression that the idea was to define the L-functions on both sides of the transfers and then we would have functoriality when we could give a "functor" that makes them agree; this is the structure that is supposed to make the transfers "unique"?

For $GL_n$ one only needs $L$-functions at unramified primes to make the transfer unique, and for other groups it need not be unique even with $L$-functions at ramified primes, so extending from unramified primes to ramified primes is not crucial for uniqueness of reciprocity (or functoriality).

I don't know what you mean by "some candidates that work for some narrow conditions" for $GL_n$. We have a formula that works for an arbitrary automorphic representation of $GL_n$ by Godement-Jacquet. For automorphic forms with associated to Galois representations, the $L$-function is the unique one that agrees with the $L$-function of (any) global Galois representation.  This suffices to fix the $L$-function of an arbitrary local representation of $GL_n$.

There are lots of approaches you could take to uniquely characterize them. I don't know what exactly you mean by "structural". If you believe GRH then, for cusp forms on $GL_n$, the usual formula is the only one that satisifes the Riemann hypothesis (together with a bound for the poles of the local factors I guess) and then for Eisenstein series of $GL_n$ it's determined by the cusp form case and the expected relation between $L$-functions of cusp forms and Eisenstein series, and then for other groups it's determined by what I said in my first comment.

@WillSawin Ok so for $GL_n$ the correspondence is unique and the L-functions are the unique ones that agree, via that unique correspondence, with the Galois L-functions. Then the transfers are uniquely determined by the definitions of L-functions at unramified primes?

@WillSawin is this paper worth reading on the matter
https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.10375
I mean is there consensus around this axiomatization.
